# passing values of two edittext fields from one activity to list view of anothers activity in android app

Tags: android

in my code i need to pass two edit text field and one image value to the list view of another activity when button is pressed.I have tried a lot of tutorials but i did not find the suitable one to match my requirement.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add more specific information - what did you already try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Can U exaplian your Question In details.. If Possible With code

Comment: There is nothing problem to pass values from second activity to first activity.My problem is how to receive those values and how i shall configure it in list view?

Answer (score 0):

try this, Use puExtra to send values from one activity to another activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("editvalue1", editbox1.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("editvalue2", editbox2.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("image_url", "your image url");
startActivity(i);
```

Get this value to next activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String edit1 = i.getStringExtra("editvalue1");
String edit2 = i.getStringExtra("editvalue2");
String url = i.getStringExtra("image_url");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply murali!I want to update the edit text values and image value to my list view which is in another activity.Can you pls guide me!

Answer (score 0):

**In your First Activity :**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(First_activity.this, Second_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ET1", et1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("ET2", et2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Image_URL", "your_image_url");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**In your Second Activity :**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(Your_Layout); 

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String first = intent.getStringExtra("ET1");
         String second = intent.getStringExtra("ET2");
         String url = intent.getStringExtra("Image_URL"); 

// Now you can set this values to your Listview.

    }
```

Comment: thanks Andrain!i am clear about with your answer.Is the correct way to dynamically add the row in list view of my second activity.It just receive the edit text values to the second view.But it is not loaded to the list view.

Comment: Actually i wanted how to pass the edit text value to the customized list view...i dont know how to implement the dynamic list view...there are lot of confusion arised.Can you pls ping me..This is my mail id:senthamilthendral@gmail.com

Comment: There is nothing problem to pass values from second activity to first activity.My problem is how to receive those values and how i shall configure it in list view?

Comment: show me your code of list view otherwise no one can't help you. @SenthamilThendralS

Answer (score 0):

at first class

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText editT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT1);
    EditText editT2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT2);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(First_activity.this,Second_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text1", et1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("text2", et2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Image_URL", "your_image_url");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

then in second class

```
    ListView List;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_second); 
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text1");
         String text2 = intent.getStringExtra("text2");


        List=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);//your listview id
        ListAdapter ListAdapter=new ListAdapter(this,text1,text2);
        List.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

    }
```

Now create your own listadapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Activity context;
    String title[];
    String description[];

    public ListAdapter (Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dital_list_view, null);//your listview layout
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);//forst textview id
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);//second text view id
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

now create listview layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    -<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/titleText"/>

    <TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/descriptionText" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i hope it be helpful